# Dealing with 213dpi density

Tags: android, dpi, screen-density

I'm currently working on adding multi-screen/density support to an app.
I've tested out most densities and everything seems to lay out and fit just fine...except on the emulator running 213dpi.

I've run into a limitation. Since the density factor is 213/160=1.33125, a single dp unit would convert to 1*1.33125=1.33125 pixels. I can't pass a decimal measurement (say my margin is 1dp), so I either round or floor. With a lot of views having a margin 1dp big, there's a huge loss of accuracy that results in layout issues.

Honestly, I highly doubt support for 213dpi is required, but how do you work with assets for such a density when there's such a high loss of accuracy at the end?

Answer (score 0):

Standard dpi sizes are 120, 160, 213, 240, 320, 480 and 640. 213 is for some TV screens, and it's used on my tablet with true density being 189ppi.

213 appears to be rounding of 213.3333... so 213.3333.../160=1.3333...

Screen density is 4/3.